# Is there a Way to Print the Session in PowerShell to a .txt?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, recording

We are doing a lot of things in PowerShell in networking and in basic servers and our instructor is having us copy and paste sessions in PowerShell into a .txt file. This is well and fine, but is there a command to print the session? Or make a log?

I know not, he knows not, we know not.

It seemed as if there were a print command, but I may be confusing that with with Write-Host

Comment: [Start-Transcript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-5.1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the
[Start-Transcript cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-5.1)
to begin recording a session.

You can optionally specify the path and filename you wish to record to, and whether to append to existing files or overwrite them. If unspecified, a file-name is generated
in the folder `C:\Users\USER\Documents`.

This will record in the text file all typed commands
and all output that appeared on the console.

To stop recording use the
[Stop-Transcript cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript?view=powershell-5.1).
Alternatively, ending a session will also stop the transcript.